# Yii2-Use SqlDataProvider with GridView and enable Gridview Filter for search

Tags: search, gridview, yii2, dropdown, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`. I have a custom view in which I have placed to views `DetailView` and `GridView`. Below is my controller code

```
public function actionViewcreated($id)// passed the id of my model which is created in the previous step
{
    $model=$this->findModel($id); // this will find my model/record based on the id

    $sub_div = $model->sub_div;
    $meter_type = $model->meter_type;

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT m.`id` AS meter_id, ins.`meter_msn` AS Meter_Serial_Number, ins.`meter_type` AS Meter_Type, sd.`sub_div_code` AS Sub_Division_Code,sd.`name` AS Sub_Division_Name 
    FROM `installations` ins 
    INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
    INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = map.`meter_type`
    INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no` 
    INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code` 
    WHERE ins.`meter_type` = '$meter_type' 
    AND sd.`sub_div_code` = '$sub_div' 
    AND map.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM 
    `meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))";


    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->set('my_sql', $query);

    $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`)  
    FROM `installations` ins 
    INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
    INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = map.`meter_type` 
    INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no` 
    INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code` 
    WHERE ins.`meter_type` = '$meter_type' 
    AND sd.`sub_div_code` = '$sub_div' 
    AND map.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM `meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))")->queryScalar();

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->set('total', $count);


    if($count <= 0)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('errors', '
 <div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
 <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
 <strong>There are no meters installed against the selected Sub Division!!!! </strong>Acceptance is not Created</div>');


        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    else
    {
        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $query,
            'totalCount' => $count,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 40,
            ],
        ]);


        return $this->render('viewcreated', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
            'id' => $model->id
            /*'searchModel' => $searchModel*/
        ]);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
 <?= DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => [

                [
                        'label'=>'Serial #',
                         'value' => function($d)
                         {
                             return $d->id;
                         }
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Meter Type',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->meter_type;
                        return ' - ';
                    },


                ],
                'sub_div',
                [
                    'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->subDiv->name;
                        return '-';
                    },


                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Prepared By',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->prepared->name;
                    },


                ],
                'prepared_at',

                'status',


            ],
        ]) ?>
        <br>
      <?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          /*'filterModel' => $searchModel,*/
          'id'=>'gv',

          'columns' => [
              ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
             return ['value' => $d['meter_id']];
         }],

         'Meter_Serial_Number',
         'Meter_Type',
         'Sub_Division_Code',
         'Sub_Division_Name',

       ],
]); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**JS**

```
 $("#chk input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

**Output**

[image]

In the above `grid view` I want to add search column for `Meter Serial Number` and dropdown for `Sub Division Name`.

**Update 1**

**Installation Model**

```
class Installations extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'installations';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['created_at', 'updated_at','imsi_no','old_meter_power','old_meter_reactive_power','new_meter_power','new_meter_reactive_power','ct_ratio','ct_ratio_quantity','cable_length','cable_type','atb_installed'], 'safe'],
        [['created_by', 'updated_by', 'status'], 'integer'],
        [['ref_no', 'meter_msn', 'billing_msn', 'customer_id','ct_ratio_quantity','cable_length','meter_type'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['tarrif', 's_load', 'ct_ratio','cable_type'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['latitude', 'longitude'], 'string', 'max' => 11],
        [['site_issues', 'istallation_status', 'comm_status'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
        [['consumer_name', 'consumer_address'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['so_person_name'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
        [['so_phone_number', 'so_person_designation','atb_installed'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'ref_no' => 'Ref No',
        'meter_msn' => 'Meter MSN',
        'billing_msn' => 'Billing MSN',
        'tarrif' => 'Tarrif',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'created_by' => 'Created By',
        'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'latitude' => 'Latitude',
        'longitude' => 'Longitude',
        'site_issues' => 'Site Issues',
        'istallation_status' => 'Installation Status',
        'comm_status' => 'Comm Status',
        'customer_id' => 'Customer ID',
        'consumer_name' => 'Consumer Name',
        'consumer_address' => 'Consumer Address',
        's_load' => 'Sanctioned Load',
        'so_person_name' => 'Person Name',
        'so_phone_number' => 'Phone Number',
        'so_person_designation' => 'Person Designation',
        'imsi_no' => 'IMSI #',
        'old_meter_power' => 'Old Meter Power (kWh)',
        'old_meter_reactive_power' => 'Old Meter Reactive Power (kVArh)',
        'new_meter_power' => 'New Meter Power (kWh)',
        'new_meter_reactive_power'=>' New Meter Reactive Power (kVArh)',
        'ct_ratio'=>'CT Ratio',
        'ct_ratio_quantity'=>'CT Ratio Quantity',
        'cable_length'=>'Cable Length',
        'cable_type'=>'Cable Type',
        'atb_installed'=>'ATB Installed',
        'meter_type'=>'Meter Type',

    ];
}

public static function getCommStatus()
{
    return [
        //'' => 'Please Select',
        'Verified' => 'Verified',
        'Failed' => 'Failed',
        'System Verified' => 'System Verified'
        //'Return Communication Failed SIM' => 'Return Communication Failed SIM'
    ];
}

public static function getInstallStatus()
{
    return [
        //'' => 'Please Select',
        'Installed' => 'Installed',
        'Not Installed' => 'Not Installed',
        'System Installed'=>'System Installed'
        //'Return Communication Failed SIM' => 'Return Communication Failed SIM'
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getInstallationImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(InstallationImages::className(), ['installation_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getImages(){
    return InstallationImages::find()->where(['installation_id' => $this->id])->all();
}

public function getSiteImages(){
    return InstallationImagesSite::find()->where(['installation_id' => $this->id])->all();
}

public function getUser(){
  return User::find()->where(['id'=>$this->created_by]);
}

public function getTeamsuser()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'created_by']);
}
}
```

**Installation Search Model**

```
class InstallationsSearch extends Installations
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
     return [
        [['id', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'status'], 'integer'],
        [['ref_no','meter_type','install_type', 'meter_msn', 'billing_msn', 
            'tarrif', 'created_at','created_by', 'updated_at', 'latitude', 
            'longitude', 'site_issues', 'istallation_status', 'comm_status', 
            'customer_id', 'consumer_name', 'consumer_address', 's_load', 
            'so_person_name', 'so_phone_number', 'so_person_designation','imsi_no',
            'meter_id' , 'Meter_Serial_Number' ,'Meter_Type','Sub_Division_Code','Sub_Division_Name'], 'safe'],
    ];


}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Installations::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
        'meter_type' => $this->meter_type,
        'install_type'=>$this->install_type,
        'istallation_status'=>$this->istallation_status,
        'status' => $this->status,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ref_no', $this->ref_no])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'meter_msn', $this->meter_msn])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'billing_msn', $this->billing_msn])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tarrif', $this->tarrif])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'latitude', $this->latitude])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'longitude', $this->longitude])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'site_issues', $this->site_issues])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'istallation_status', $this->istallation_status])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'comm_status', $this->comm_status])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_id', $this->customer_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'consumer_name', $this->consumer_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'consumer_address', $this->consumer_address])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 's_load', $this->s_load])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'so_person_name', $this->so_person_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'so_phone_number', $this->so_phone_number])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like','meter_type',$this->meter_type])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like','created_by',$this->created_by])
        //->andFilterWhere(['like', 'imsi_no', $this->imsi_no])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'so_person_designation', $this->so_person_designation]);

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role, [3,4])) {
        $query->joinWith('teamsuser', true);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'user.group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id]);
    }
    $query->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

How can I add these two options in the grid view?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update 2**

As per answer given I have updated my code

**InstallationsSearch**

```
class InstallationsSearch extends Installations
{

public $meter_id;
public $Meter_Serial_Number;
public $Meter_Type;
public $Sub_Division_Code;
public $Sub_Division_Name;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'status'], 'integer'],
        [['ref_no','meter_type','install_type', 'meter_msn', 'billing_msn', 'tarrif', 'created_at','created_by', 'updated_at', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'site_issues', 'istallation_status', 'comm_status', 'customer_id', 'consumer_name', 'consumer_address', 's_load', 'so_person_name', 'so_phone_number', 'so_person_designation','imsi_no','meter_id' , 'Meter_Serial_Number' ,'Meter_Type','Sub_Division_Code','Sub_Division_Name'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Installations::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
        'meter_type' => $this->meter_type,
        'install_type'=>$this->install_type,
        'istallation_status'=>$this->istallation_status,
        'status' => $this->status,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ref_no', $this->ref_no])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'meter_msn', $this->meter_msn])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'billing_msn', $this->billing_msn])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tarrif', $this->tarrif])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'latitude', $this->latitude])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'longitude', $this->longitude])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'site_issues', $this->site_issues])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'istallation_status', $this->istallation_status])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'comm_status', $this->comm_status])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_id', $this->customer_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'consumer_name', $this->consumer_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'consumer_address', $this->consumer_address])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 's_load', $this->s_load])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'so_person_name', $this->so_person_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'so_phone_number', $this->so_phone_number])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like','meter_type',$this->meter_type])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like','created_by',$this->created_by])
        //->andFilterWhere(['like', 'imsi_no', $this->imsi_no])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'so_person_designation', $this->so_person_designation]);

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role, [3,4])) {
        $query->joinWith('teamsuser', true);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'user.group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id]);
    }
    $query->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    return $dataProvider;
}

/**
 * @param $params
 * @return SqlDataProvider
 * @throws \yii\db\Exception
 */
public function searchInstallations($params )
{

    $query = /** @lang text */
        "SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.`id` AS meter_id, 
    ins.`meter_msn` AS Meter_Serial_Number, 
    ins.`meter_type` AS Meter_Type, 
    sd.`sub_div_code` AS Sub_Division_Code,
    sd.`name` AS Sub_Division_Name 
    FROM `installations` ins 
    INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
    INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = 
    map.`meter_type`
    INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no` 
    INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = 
    sd.`sub_div_code` 
    WHERE ins.`meter_type` = :meter_type 
    AND sd.`sub_div_code` = :sub_div 
    AND map.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM 
    `meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))";
    $queryParams = [
        ':meter_type' => $params['meter_type'] ,
        ':sub_div' => $params['sub_div']
    ];

    $queryCount = /** @lang text */
        "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`)  
    FROM `installations` ins 
    INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
    INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = map.`meter_type` 
    INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no` 
    INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code` 
    WHERE ins.`meter_type` = :meter_type 
    AND sd.`sub_div_code` = :sub_div 
    AND map.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM 
    `meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))";


    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider ( [
        'sql' => $query ,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 60 ,
        ] ,
    ] );

    if ( !($this->load ( $params ) && $this->validate ()) ) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    if($this->Meter_Serial_Number!==''){
        $dataProvider->sql .= ' AND ins.meter_msn like :meter_serial_number';
        $queryParams[':meter_serial_number'] = $this->Meter_Serial_Number . '%';
        $queryCount .= ' AND ins.meter_msn like :meter_serial_number';
    }

    if($this->Sub_Division_Code!==''){
        $dataProvider->sql .= ' AND sd.sub_div_code like :sub_div_code';
        $queryParams[':sub_div_code'] = $this->Sub_Division_Code . '%';
        $queryCount .= ' AND sd.sub_div_code like :sub_div_code';
    }

    $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand ( $queryCount , $queryParams )->queryScalar ();

    $dataProvider->totalCount = $count;
    $dataProvider->params = $queryParams;

    //add to session
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->set ( 'my_sql' , Yii::$app->db->createCommand ( $query , $queryParams )->rawSql );
    $session->set ( 'total' , $count );

    //return data provider
    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

**Controler Code**

```
 public function actionViewcreated( $id ) {// passed the id of my model which is created in the previous step
    $model = $this->findModel ( $id ); // this will find my model/record based on the id
    $sub_div = $model->sub_div;
    $meter_type = $model->meter_type;

    $queryParams = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    $queryParams['sub_div'] = $sub_div;
    $queryParams['meter_type'] = $meter_type;

    $searchModel = new InstallationsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchInstallations( $queryParams );

    if ( Yii::$app->session->get ( 'total' ) <= 0 ) {
        $this->findModel ( $id )->delete ();

        \Yii::$app->getSession ()->setFlash ( 'errors' , '
        <div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" 
        type="button">×</button>
        <strong>There are no meters installed against the selected Sub Division!!!! </strong>Acceptance is not Created</div>' );


        return $this->redirect ( [ 'index' , 'id' => $model->id ] );
    }



    return $this->render ( 'viewcreated' , [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider ,
        'model' => $model ,
        'id' => $model->id ,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel
    ] );
}
```

**View**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            //'ajaxUpdate'       => true,
            //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'id'=>'gv',

            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
                    return ['value' => $d['meter_id']];
                }],

                [
                    'attribute'=>'Meter_Serial_Number',
                    'filter'=> \yii\helpers\Html::activeTextInput($searchModel, 'Meter_Serial_Number',['class'=>'form-control']),
                ],
                'Meter_Type',
                'Sub_Division_Code',
                [
                    'attribute' => 'Sub_Division_Name',
                    'filter'=> \yii\helpers\Html::activeTextInput($searchModel,'Sub_Division_Name', ['class'=>'form-control']),
                ],


            ],
        ]); ?>
```

**Update 3**

After updating my code I got search filters on both the `Meter Serial` and `Sub Division`

[image]

But when I try to search a serial number then the page got refreshed and again I see the full view

By `echo $dataProvider->sql;` I got

`SELECT DISTINCT m.`id`AS meter_id, ins.`meter_msn`AS Meter_Serial_Number, ins.`meter_type`AS Meter_Type, sd.`sub_div_code`AS Sub_Division_Code, sd.`name`AS Sub_Division_Name FROM`installations`ins INNER JOIN`meters`m ON ins.`meter_msn`= m.`meter_msn`INNER JOIN`meter_acceptance_header`map ON ins.`meter_type`= map.`meter_type`INNER JOIN`survey`sur ON ins.`ref_no`= sur.`ref_no`INNER JOIN`survey_hesco_subdivision`sd ON sur.`sub_division`= sd.`sub_div_code`WHERE ins.`meter_type`= :meter_type AND sd.`sub_div_code`= :sub_div AND map.`id`NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id`FROM`meter_acceptance_details`md WHERE md.`flag`IN (1)) AND ins.meter_msn like :meter_serial_number AND sd.sub_div_code like :sub_div_code`

The above query remains the same whether I have searched for any serial number or not.

**Note:** I already know how to add a search option by adding a filter field in a calculated column in my search model. But as I have a custom view so I am confused that how can I do it.

Comment: add your `Installation` and `InstallationSearch` model.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam bro I have added both

Comment: are you using the `InstallationSearch` model anywhere else in your app for searching the installations ?

Comment: also what does the `findModel()` function return?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam here it is `protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Installations::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes `InstallationSearch` is used in `Installations`  module

Comment: i added an answer

Comment: can you check if `$this->load($params)` return `true` or `false`  ? i think it is returning `false` that why you are not getting any results

Comment: I have updated the check , there was a mistake , we need to pass the default params if in case no params are provided or gridview loads by default, because we have 2 default parameter bindings, `:meter_type ` and `:sub_div ` which need to be passed a value if there are no search params or search string provided, and that was the reason of the error you were receiving when you integrated it, so revert the changes of the `if` check that we did , and copy the `searchInstallation()` function again.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Applied but still the same result. You can check my `update 3`

Comment: Secondly it's showing me `Showing 1-28 of 0 items.`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam by little debugging I found that the code always goes inside the the check `if ( !($this->load ( $params ) && $this->validate ()) ) {
            print_r('hi');
            
            $dataProvider->params=$queryParams;
            return $dataProvider;
        }`

Comment: by default it will always go into the check, i have updated the check again , as the `$dataProvider->count` also need to be set, thats why you are getting thte wrong count , copy the code for the `if` check again and verify if the count is alright ? but it should not go into the check if you provide any search text into the fields. can you verify that too

Comment: It's still going inside the if condition while searching

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177655/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-aslam-and-mr-faisal).

Comment: haha ji ji zarur :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have'nt used it quite though with the GridView and there could be better solutions than this one if anyone could suggest but this can work the way you want.

You should update your `InstallationSearch` model to use the filter with the `GridView`.If you are not using the default `InstallationSearch` model's `search()` function anywhere then you can update the existing search method or else create a separate method. I assume you are not using it anywhere else and I will add a search function that will use the `SqlDataProvider` for displaying and filtering the `GridView`.

To implement the search you need to identify how many aliases are you using for the columns you have to declare all of them as `public attributes` of your search model

```
public $meter_id;
public $Meter_Serial_Number;
public $Meter_Type;
public $Sub_Division_Code;
public $Sub_Division_Name;
```

then add them to the safe rule

```
public function rules() {
        return [
                [ [ 'meter_id' , 'Meter_Serial_Number' ,'Meter_Type','Sub_Division_Code','Sub_Division_Name'] , 'safe' ] ,
        ];
}
```

Now add the `search()` function

```
public function searchInstallations($params)
{
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT
            m.`id` AS meter_id,
            ins.`meter_msn` AS Meter_Serial_Number,
            ins.`meter_type` AS Meter_Type,
            sd.`sub_div_code` AS Sub_Division_Code,
            sd.`name` AS Sub_Division_Name
            FROM `installations` ins
            INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
            INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = map.`meter_type`
            INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no`
            INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code`
            WHERE ins.`meter_type` = :meter_type
            AND sd.`sub_div_code` = :sub_div
            AND map.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM
            `meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))";

    $queryParams = [
        ':meter_type' => $params['meter_type'],
        ':sub_div' => $params['sub_div']
    ];

    $queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`)
                FROM `installations` ins
                INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
                INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = map.`meter_type`
                INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no`
                INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code`
                WHERE ins.`meter_type` = :meter_type
                AND sd.`sub_div_code` = :sub_div
                AND map.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM `meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))";

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider(
        [
            'sql' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 40
            ]
        ]
    );

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        $dataProvider->params = $queryParams;
        $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($queryCount, $queryParams)->queryScalar();
        $dataProvider->totalCount = $count;
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    if ($this->Meter_Serial_Number !== '') {
        $dataProvider->sql .= ' AND ins.meter_msn like :meter_serial_number';
        $queryParams[':meter_serial_number'] = $this->Meter_Serial_Number . '%';
        $queryCount .= ' AND ins.meter_msn like :meter_serial_number';
    }

    if ($this->Sub_Division_Code !== '') {
        $dataProvider->sql .= ' AND sd.sub_div_code like :sub_div_code';
        $queryParams[':sub_div_code'] = $this->Sub_Division_Code . '%';
        $queryCount .= ' AND sd.sub_div_code like :sub_div_code';
    }

    $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($queryCount, $queryParams)->queryScalar();

    $dataProvider->totalCount = $count;
    $dataProvider->params = $queryParams;

    //add to session
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->set('my_sql', Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query, $queryParams)->rawSql);
    $session->set('total', $count);

    //return data provider
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Update your `actionViewcreated` to the following

```
public function actionViewcreated($id)
{
    // passed the id of my model which is created in the previous step
    $model = $this->findModel($id); // this will find my model/record based on the id
    $sub_div = $model->sub_div;
    $meter_type = $model->meter_type;

    $queryParams = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    $queryParams['sub_div'] = $sub_div;
    $queryParams['meter_type'] = $meter_type;

    $searchModel = new InstallationSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchInstallation($queryParams);

    if (Yii::$app->session->get('total') <= 0) {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash(
            'errors',
            '<div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable"><button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            <strong>There are no meters installed against the selected Sub Division!!!! </strong>Acceptance is not Created</div>'
        );

        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render(
        'viewcreated', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
            'id' => $model->id,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel
        ]
    );
}
```

and enable the filter for the grid view like below

```
[
    'attribute'=>'Meter_Serial_Number',
    'filter'=> \yii\helpers\Html::activeTextInput($searchModel, 'Meter_Serial_Number',['class'=>'form-control']),
],
[
    'attribute' => 'Sub_Division_Name',
    'filter'=> \yii\helpers\Html::activeTextInput($searchModel,'Sub_Division_Name', ['class'=>'form-control']),
],
```

### `EDIT`

For making your dropdown work either change the function `toArrayList()` to the following if it is not used anywhere else or create a separate function as you need to have the `sub_div_name` as the value to be searched in the table so change the `sub_div_code` to the field which has the `sub_div_name` i assume it is the `name` field in the `SurveyHescoSubdivision` .

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function toArrayList()
{
    return ArrayHelper::map(
        self::find()->all(), 'name', function ($model, $defaultValue) {
            return $model['sub_div_code'] . ' - ' . $model['name'];
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `'filter'=> \yii\helpers\Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel,'Sub_Division_Name', \common\models\SurveyHescoSubdivision::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Sub-Div", 'class' => 'form-control'])` dropdown search is not working

Comment: what is the output of the `toArrayList()` it should have `"id"=>"label"` format? @MrFaisal

Comment: This is the function `public static function toArrayList(){
        return ArrayHelper::map(self::find()->all(),'sub_div_code',function($model, $defaultValue){
            return $model['sub_div_code'].' - '.$model['name'];
        });
    }`