# Yii2- Unable to upload image

Tags: php, html, file-upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`. In one of my view, I am trying to upload an image. But I am unable to upload it.

**Model**

```
class MeterAcceptanceHeader extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

public static $status_titles =[
    0 => 'Prepared',
    1 => 'Created',
    2 => 'Printed',
    3 => 'Canceled',
];

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'meter_acceptance_header';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['sub_div', 'prepared_by'], 'required'],
        [['prepared_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
        [['prepared_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['sub_div', 'meter_type', 'status'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['images'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['images'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png,jpg,pdf', 'maxFiles' => 4],
        [['sub_div'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => SurveyHescoSubdivision::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['sub_div' => 'sub_div_code']],
        [['prepared_by'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['prepared_by' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'sub_div' => 'Sub Div',
        'meter_type' => 'Meter Type',
        'prepared_by' => 'Prepared By',
        'prepared_at' => 'Prepared At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
        'images' => 'Document Snap',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getMeterAcceptanceDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MeterAcceptanceDetails::className(), ['accpt_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getSubDiv()
{
    return $this->hasOne(SurveyHescoSubdivision::className(), ['sub_div_code' => 'sub_div']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPrepared()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'prepared_by']);
}
}
```

**MeterAcceptanceHeader Table**

[image]

**MeterAcceptanceImages Table**

[image]

There is a `form1` in which user is prompt to select from the dropdown.

**Form1 View**

```
<div class="meter-acceptance-header-form">
<?php $model->status = common\models\MeterAcceptanceHeader::$status_titles[0]; ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'acceptance-form','options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'sub_div')->dropDownList([''=>'Please Select'] + \common\models\SurveyHescoSubdivision::toArrayList()) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'meter_type')->dropDownList([''=>'Please Select','Single-Phase' => 'Single-Phase', '3-Phase' => '3-Phase', 'L.T.TOU' => 'L.T.TOU']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'readonly' => true]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.history.back()" href="javascript:;"><i
                class="fa fa-close"></i>
        Cancel</a>
    <a class="<?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary' ?>" onclick="
      $('#acceptance-form').submit();" href="javascript:">
        <?= $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update' ?></a>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

After clicking on `Create` button the user is prompt to the second form in which a user will upload an image.

Below is my code for the controller from which I am trying to upload it.

```
public function actionSetpdf($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $m = 0;
    $accpt_id = $model->id;
    $meter_type = $model->meter_type;
    $ogp_sub_div = $model->sub_div;
    $images=[];
    $ic=0;
    $files_uploaded = false;
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
        $data = explode(',',$_POST['data']);

        foreach($data as $value)
        {

            $m = new MeterAcceptanceDetails;
            $m -> load(Yii::$app->request->post());

            $m->accpt_id = $accpt_id;
            $m->meter_type = $meter_type;
            $m->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $m->created_by = Yii::$app->user->id;
            $m->meter_id = $value;
            $m->meter_msn = \common\models\Meters::idTomsn($value);
            $m->flag = 1;// 1 means created
            $m->ogp_sub_div = $ogp_sub_div;

            if($m->save())
            { 
                // Here the upload image code starts
                if($ic==0)
                {

                    $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images');
                    foreach ($model->images as $file)
                    {
                        if (file_exists($file->tempName))
                        {
                            $img_s = new MeterAcceptanceImages;
                            $file_name = rand(0, 1000) . time().date('his') . '.' . $file->extension;
                            $file->saveAs('uploads/meter_acceptance/' . $file_name);
                            $img_s->file_path = $file_name;
                            $img_s->accpt_id = $accpt_id;

                            if ($img_s->save()) {
                                $images[] = $img_s;

                            } else {
                                print_r($img_s->getErrors());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    foreach($images as $image){
                        $img_s = new MeterAcceptanceImages;
                        $img_s->file_path = $image->file_path;
                        $img_s->accpt_id = $accpt_id;
                        $img_s->save();
                    }
                }

                $model->status = MeterAcceptanceHeader::$status_titles[1];
                $model->update();

            }
            else{

                $this->renderAjax('viewcreated');
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        $this->renderAjax('viewcreated');
    }


    return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/viewsetpdf','id' => $model->id,'model' => $this->findModel($id)]));

}
```

**Form2 View**

```
<div class="map-meters-form" id="doc">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'map-form', 'enableClientValidation' => true, 'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
<section class="content">
<div class="box">
    <div id="chk" class="box-body">
        <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
        <?= DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => [

                [
                        'label'=>'Serial #',
                         'value' => function($d)
                         {
                             return $d->id;
                         }
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Meter Type',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->meter_type;
                        return ' - ';
                    },


                ],
                'sub_div',
                [
                    'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->subDiv->name;
                        return '-';
                    },


                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Prepared By',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->prepared->name;
                    },


                ],
                'prepared_at',

                'status',


            ],
        ]) ?>
        <br>
        <div class="pre-scrollable">
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            //'ajaxUpdate'       => true,
            'filterModel' => false,
            //'id'=>'gv',

            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
                    return ['value' => $d['meter_id']];
                }],
                'Meter_Serial_Number',
                'Meter_Type',
                'Sub_Division_Code',
                'Sub_Division_Name',
            ],
        ]); ?>
        </div>
        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'images[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*'])?>
        <br>
        <form>
            <p>
                <a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/setpdf', 'id'=>$model->id])?>" name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Submit</a>

                <br/>

            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php
  $url = Url::toRoute(['/meteracceptanceheader/setpdf','id'=>$model->id]);
  $script = <<< JS
  $(document).ready(function () {  

  $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
  $("#chk").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  });
  $("#chk").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);

  $('#myid').on('click',function(e) {


   e.preventDefault();    
   var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!=="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
       strValue = this.value;     

  });

  $.ajax({
     url: '$url',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {data:strValue},         
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
     }
  });
  }) 
  });
  JS;
  $this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
  ?>
```

This will allow selecting an image. Now when I try to click submit button I am getting below error

> PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 0'
>
> in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php:330

By debugging the controller code I found that the error comes at `foreach ($model->images as $file)` as `print_r($model->images)` return `Array()` empty.

By doing `print_r($model)` I got

```
common\models\MeterAcceptanceHeader Object ( [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 1 [sub_div] => 37111 [meter_type] => L.T.TOU [prepared_by] => 12 [prepared_at] => 2018-08-20 12:41:27 [updated_at] => [status] => Prepared [updated_by] => [images] => Array ( ) ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 1 [sub_div] => 37111 [meter_type] => L.T.TOU [prepared_by] => 12 [prepared_at] => 2018-08-20 12:41:27 [updated_at] => [status] => Prepared [updated_by] => [images] => ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) )
```

I have used the same process in other modules as well and it works properly.

How can I get rid of this problem?

**Update 1**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use app\models\User;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use kartik\file\FileInput;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */
$this->title = $model->id;
$this->title = 'Meter Acceptance Form';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<section class="content-header">
   <h1>Meter Acceptance</h1>
</section>
<div class="map-meters-form" id="doc">

<section class="content">
    <div class="box">
        <div id="chk" class="box-body">
            <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
            <?=
            DetailView::widget([
                'model' => $model,
                'attributes' => [
                    [
                        'label' => 'Serial #',
                        'value' => function($d){
                            return $d->id;
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => 'Meter Type',
                        'value' => function ($d){
                            if( is_object($d) )
                                return $d->meter_type;
                            return ' - ';
                        },
                    ],
                    'sub_div',
                    [
                        'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
                        'value' => function ($d){
                            if( is_object($d) )
                                return $d->subDiv->name;
                            return '-';
                        },
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => 'Prepared By',
                        'value' => function ($d){
                            if( is_object($d) )
                                return $d->prepared->name;
                        },
                    ],
                    'prepared_at',
                    'status',
                ],
            ])
            ?>
            <br>
            <div class="pre-scrollable">
                <?=
                GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    //'ajaxUpdate'       => true,
                    'filterModel' => false,
                    //'id'=>'gv',
                    'columns' => [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d){
                            return ['value' => $d['meter_id']];
                        }],
                        'Meter_Serial_Number',
                        'Meter_Type',
                        'Sub_Division_Code',
                        'Sub_Division_Name',
                    ],
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
            <?php
            $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'map-form', 'enableClientValidation' => true, 'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']])
            ?>
            <?=$form->field($model, 'images[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>
            <br>
            <p>
                <a href="<?=URL::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/setpdf', 'id' => $model->id]) ?>" name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Submit</a>

                <br/>

            </p>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['/meteracceptanceheader/setpdf','id'=>$model->id]);
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function () {  

$(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
       $("#chk").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
});
      $("#chk").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);

   $('#myid').on('click',function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();    

 //START Append form data
  var data = new FormData();

  var files= $('input[name="MeterAcceptanceHeader[images][]"]')[0].files;

  //append files
  $.each(files,function(index,file){
      data.append("MeterAcceptanceHeader[images][]",file,file.name);
  });


 var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!=="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
       strValue = this.value;     

});
    //alert(strValue);

    //append your query string to the form data too
  data.append('data',strValue);

  //END append form data
  $.ajax({
     url: '$url',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
     data: {data:strValue},         
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
     }
     });

     }) 
     });
     JS;
     $this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
     ?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What looks like that you are trying to submit an image via Ajax call when you click on submit button in the step 2 for image upload as you are binding the `click` to the `#myid` which is the anchor button

```
<a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/setpdf', 'id'=>$model->id])?>" name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Submit</a>
```

And if you are trying to send the image via ajax you need to use the `FormData` interface.

> The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of 
>   key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can
>   then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses
>   the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to
>   "multipart/form-data".

But before I address how to do it, you need to look into some other issues related to `Form2` view.

- You are nesting the 2 forms which is technically wrong and you can't do that see [`Why`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element).
- Above all why are you creating a separate form for the submit button?

  see this line on top

  ```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'map-form', 'enableClientValidation' => true, 'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
  'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
  ```

  This is where your first form starts and the file input field

  `<?= $form->field($model, 'images[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*'])?>`

  is inside this form, and on the very next line you have the anchor button that i mentioned above in the start but you are wrapping it inside a separate form and that too before you close the `ActiveForm`

  ```
     <form>
          <p>
              <a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/setpdf', 'id'=>$model->id])?>" name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Submit</a>

              <br/>

          </p>
      </form>
  ```

  instead you are closing the `ActiveForm` after this form by calling `<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>`. As you have seen in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648116/yii2-use-sqldataprovider-with-gridview-and-enable-gridview-filter-for-search) that you faced weird behavior with the filter inputs for the `GridVew` as you were wrapping the `GridView` inside the form, and you are repeating that same mistake here too and also nesting 2 forms within.

What i will advise you to do first

- Remove the form that you are creating just for the anchor button, as you wont be needing it if you want to submit the image via ajax by clicking on the anchor just keep the anchor inside the main `ActiveForm`. And Move the `ActiveForm::begin()` just before the `fileInput()` and after the `Pjax::end()`.

With that said you should now user `FormData` to upload the image via ajax and to do so you have to add these options `contentType: false` and `processData: false` inside your ajax call and use `FormData.append()` to append the input files to the `FormData`.

So your javascript for the click function will look like this, i assume the model used for the image upload is `MeterAcceptanceImages`

```
$('#myid').on('click',function(e) {
      event.preventDefault();

      //START Append form data
      let data = new FormData();

      let files= $("input[name='MeterAcceptanceImages[images][]']")[0].files;

      //append files
      $.each(files,function(index,file){
          data.append('MeterAcceptanceImages[images][]',file,file.name);
      });

      var strValue = "";
      $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {
           if(strValue!==""){
               strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;
           }else{
              strValue = this.value;     
           }
      });

      //append your query string to the form data too
      data.append('data',strValue);

      //END append form data

      $.ajax({
          url: '$url',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
          }
      });
});
```

So overall your view `Form2.php` should look like below

```
<div class="map-meters-form" id="doc">

    <section class="content">
        <div class="box">
            <div id="chk" class="box-body">
                <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
                <?=
                DetailView::widget([
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attributes' => [
                        [
                            'label' => 'Serial #',
                            'value' => function($d){
                                return $d->id;
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            'label' => 'Meter Type',
                            'value' => function ($d){
                                if( is_object($d) )
                                    return $d->meter_type;
                                return ' - ';
                            },
                        ],
                        'sub_div',
                        [
                            'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
                            'value' => function ($d){
                                if( is_object($d) )
                                    return $d->subDiv->name;
                                return '-';
                            },
                        ],
                        [
                            'label' => 'Prepared By',
                            'value' => function ($d){
                                if( is_object($d) )
                                    return $d->prepared->name;
                            },
                        ],
                        'prepared_at',
                        'status',
                    ],
                ])
                ?>
                <br>
                <div class="pre-scrollable">
                    <?=
                    GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        //'ajaxUpdate'       => true,
                        'filterModel' => false,
                        //'id'=>'gv',
                        'columns' => [
                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d){
                                    return ['value' => $d['meter_id']];
                                }],
                            'Meter_Serial_Number',
                            'Meter_Type',
                            'Sub_Division_Code',
                            'Sub_Division_Name',
                        ],
                    ]);
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
                <?php
                $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'map-form', 'enableClientValidation' => true, 'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                            'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']])
                ?>
                <?=$form->field($model, 'images[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <a href="<?=URL::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/setpdf', 'id' => $model->id]) ?>" name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Submit</a>

                    <br/>

                </p>
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['/meteracceptanceheader/setpdf', 'id' => $model->id]);
$script = <<< JS
  $(document).ready(function () {  

  $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    $("#chk").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  });
  $("#chk").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);

$('#myid').on('click',function(e) {
      event.preventDefault();

      //START Append form data
      let data = new FormData();

      let files= $("input[name='MeterAcceptanceImages[images][]']")[0].files;

      //append files
      $.each(files,function(index,file){
          data.append('MeterAcceptanceImages[images][]',file,file.name);
      });

      var strValue = "";
      $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {
           if(strValue!==""){
               strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;
           }else{
              strValue = this.value;     
           }
      });

      //append your query string to the form data too
      data.append('data',strValue);

      //END append form data

      $.ajax({
          url: '$url',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
          }
      });
});

  });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
?>
```

Now if you try to `print_r(UploadedFile::getInstances('images'))` should show you all the images you selected and submitted to upload. To troubleshoot in case of errors while uploading of the ajax call you can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113850/i-am-getting-error-in-php-while-uploading-image-to-databse-using-jquery-the-dat/51119586#51119586) i posted previously related to ajax file uploads.

Comment: `let` is not supported

Comment: I have used `var data = new FormData();

      var files= $('input[name="MeterAcceptanceHeader[images][]"]')[0].files;`

Comment: And applied your suggested changes. But while submitting I am getting `PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: model' 

in E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\backend\views\meteracceptanceheader\viewcreated.php:18`

Comment: Line # 18 is `$this->title = $model->id;`

Comment: is the above line `$this->title = $model->id;` inside the view i dont think so? and what do you mean `let` is not supported ? i have tested the solution and it works well , can you please confirm the things asked

Comment: Let definations are not supported by current JavaScript version. I am getting this error

Comment: @MrFaisal which browser are you using which throws the exception for `let` statement, or it is the editor that shows the error. and the error for the line `$this->title = $model->id;` does not make sense as you are overriding the title in the very next line `$this->title = 'Meter Acceptance Form';` so you can remove the line `$this->title = $model->id;` from your view.

Comment: I have updated my `JS`  now `let` is working. Furthermore, if I remove `$this->title = $model->id` then I again get the same error inside the `gridview =>` that is at line `'model' => $model,`

Comment: @MrFaisal that is because you need to pass the `$model` from the `controller/action` to the view, that is just basic thing as you are passiong the `$model` to the `DetailView` widget

Comment: I have already passed it and it was working previously. But after adding `contentType: false,
          processData: false,` it's giving me this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178845/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-aslam-and-mr-faisal).